# iOS google streetview api

Tags: ios, google-street-view

I would like to set up a web page with "browseable" streetview on an iPad(the newest one)..  I've noticed that the scrolling controls and the little compass type view on streetview seem to require flash, which is not available on the iPad.  So is it possible to have basic scrolling, panorama etc, with just JavaScript and no flash?.

Thanks, Aleks.

Answer (score 1):

iOS 6 is under NDA and cannot be discussed here. Please direct all questions to http://devforums.apple.com

Comment: Thanks, I will refrase the question, it really does not matter if it is ios 6 or 5 issue is the same..